# Lazarus: fatal error when opening an "output" procedure in another procedure

Tags: lazarus

So I just worked on a generic program for school which uses the sort algorithms. The teacher always loves putting everything into different units so I decided to create an "output" procedure which gives an output of the sorted array.

```
unit selectionsort;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, typen, ausgabe;
procedure SSort (FeldS: t_Feld);

implementation
procedure SSort (FeldS: t_Feld);
var h,j,min,hilf: integer;
begin
  for h:= 1 to c-1 do
      begin
        ## all the sorting stuff
      end;
  **ausgabe(FeldS);**
end;
end.
```

(ausgabe is german for output)

```
unit ausgabe;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, typen;
procedure ausgabe(FeldA: t_feld);

implementation
procedure ausgabe(FeldA: t_feld);
begin
    for i:= 1 to c do
      begin
        write(FeldA[i], ' ');
      end;

  readln();
end;

end.
```

The bold part (when calling the procedure ausgabe) is where I get the error: fatal: Syntax error, "." expected but "(" found. I know I could just delete the procedure "Ausgabe" and do the output in the sort procedures but I would like to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the procedure `ausgabe` and the unit have the same name (this is possible as they are in different scopes), the compiler assume a so-called "qualified identifier": `unitname.procedurename`. This is needed if multiple units have identifiers with the same name. To overcome the error: Either you rename the unit or the procedure or you call the procedure using its qualified name (the first `ausgabe` is the name of the unit where the compiler should search for the symbol, the second `ausgabe` is the actual procedure name):

`ausgabe.ausgabe(FeldS);`

Comment: Thank! Helped a lot.